# In GDB how to fill a memory from a file

Tags: gdb

We have dump command in GDB which will dump a particular memory to a file. I want a command which will do exactly reverse of dump command i.e, which will read from a file of a particular length and dump it to specified address(memory).

Please help me on this regards, whether the command exists. If the command does not exists then please guide me how exactly i need to go ahead and implement it. As a am new to GDB.

I tried to use restore, but the problem is i need to load a file to a particular memory location some length. And in restore command syntax there is no such thing

Comment: This question would invite more answers if you told us what research you already did. What did you read, where did you look for answers? Otherwise it seems like a google search away…

Answer (score 9):

A raw file [PATH] can be loaded to target's memory address [ADDR] with:

```
restore [PATH] binary [ADDR]
```

cf: [GDB documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dump_002fRestore-Files.html#Dump_002fRestore-Files)

Answer (score 3):

See the restore command:

> restore -- Restore the contents of FILE to target memory

with python there is also the Inferior.write_memory function

Comment: I tried to use restore, but the problem is i need to load a file to a particular memory location some length. And in restore command syntax there is no such thing.